# Invalid or unexpected MouseEvent object

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mouseevent, offscreentabs

I am trying to send [Mouse Event](https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html#method-sendMouseEvent) to my Offscreen Tab and I received following error:

```
Error during experimental.offscreenTabs.sendMouseEvent:
 Invalid or unexpected MouseEvent object
```

**My Code:**

```
chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs.sendMouseEvent(tab.id, {
    "type": "click",
    "altKey": false,
    "ctrlKey": false,
    "shiftKey": false
}, {
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10
}, function () {
    console.log("Mouse Event Sent");
});
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `button` key as well if you use a mouse event.

```
{
    "type": "click",
    "button": 1,      // 0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right
    "altKey": false,
    "ctrlKey": false,
    "shiftKey": false
}
```

Since the API is experimental, and the documentation is not quite complete, I looked in the source code:

- [chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/offscreen_tabs/offscreen_tabs_api.cc](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/offscreen_tabs/offscreen_tabs_api.cc) (implementation of the offscreenTabs API)
- [chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/public/WebInputEvent.h](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/public/WebInputEvent.h&exact_package=chromium&q=ButtonLeft&l=292) (for definitions of the "button" constants).

PS. I managed to get a Developer tools instance when I used `button: 2`. Quite useful for debugging interaction with an offscreen tab!

Comment: Thanks it solved, BTW how did you get developers tools instance to a offscreen tab ? :) did you use Debugger API()'s ?

Comment: @Sudarshan No, button=2 opens a contextmenu here (Chrome 23 / ArchLinux). There, I choose "Inspect element".

Comment: I took a complete different meaning for `I managed to get a Developer tools instance when I used button: 2. Quite useful for debugging interaction with an offscreen tab!` :), my bad.. i got it .. thanks :)